# Visualizing gseKEGG results using gene symbols

Tags: r

I am doing KEGG GSEA analysis on R, using the function fgsea.
I have provided a list of ranked fold changes, with gene identification in the form of Entrez ID. The following is my code used:

```
    ## GSEA using gene sets from KEGG pathways

    gseaKEGG <- gseKEGG(geneList = foldchanges, # ordered named vector of fold changes (Entrez IDs 
    are the associated names) 
    organism = "hsa", # supported organisms listed below
    minGSSize = 20, # minimum gene set size (# genes in set) 
    pvalueCutoff = 0.05, # padj cutoff value
    verbose = FALSE)

    ## Extract the GSEA results
    gseaKEGG_results <- gseaKEGG@result

    ## Write GSEA results to file
    View(gseaKEGG_results)
```

On the last column, the GSEA results includes a list of genes driving the enriched pathway in the form of Entrez ID and separated by "/" as follows:
7432/3354/6754/3952/10874/83551/1392/2488/4986/2892/5173/1910/3358/5539/3375/55879/2556/186/165829 (Not the complete list; for illustration purpose)

I understand that KEGG database uses Entrez ID as inputs. However, I would like to visualize these genes driving the enriched pathway in the form of the HUGO gene symbols instead. Is there a way to generate GSEA results that show gene symbols instead of Entrez ID (without doing it manually as that is logistically too tedious and time-consuming for large number of pathways)?

Any advice and help is greatly appreciated. Thank you for reading this post.

Comment: it seems that you are using clusterprofiler. see http://yulab-smu.top/clusterProfiler-book/chapter14.html#setReadable

Comment: hope this solves your issue.. if not, please provide an example dataset to reproduce the above

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I managed to get it @StupidWolf